# iptables - redirects to local network causes connectivity issues

Tags: linux, router, iptables, connection, icmp

I have 2 Debian routers and network set up like this:

```
    |
    |
    | Internet/Public IP
    |
----------
 ROUTER A 
----------
    |
    | 10.97.0.1/16
    |
    |                    10.97.64.1/16   --------
    +---------------------------------- | Client |
    |                                    --------
    |
    | 10.97.0.2/16
----------
 ROUTER B
----------
    |
    | 10.98.0.1/30
    |
    |                     10.98.0.2/30   --------
    +---------------------------------- | Server |
                                         --------
```

I set up the ROUTER A to be the default gateway for Client so it can reach the internet and I also configured a static route on ROUTER A so the Server on 10.98.0.2 is reachable, like so:

`ip route add 10.98.0.0/16 via 10.97.0.2`

Then I added iptables rule on ROUTER A to also allow Client to reach the Server:

`-A FORWARD -s 10.97.0.0/16 -d 10.98.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT`

Now the issue I'm facing is that this setup, on Client side, causes ICMP redirects, packet loss and SSH connectivity issues (sometimes it connects, sometimes it doesn't) which leads me to believe there will be problems with other protocols as well. I could of course manually setup static route on Client and explicitly specify to use ROUTER B for communication related to 10.98.0.0/16 network, which I did for testing purposes and it's working so far, but I would like to avoid this if possible and use only the ROUTER A as there will be multiple clients eventually and it would mean that I need to set up static route for each one of them.

`net.ipv4.ip_forward` is enabled and I have no problems with routing except for this case.

Thanks!

P.S: I'm running this setup in virtual environment at the moment before deploying it on real hardware.

Comment: Can you label the interfaces of each router? Are both routers on the same ethernet (and why)?

Comment: Have you tried setting accept_redirect = 0 (ie do not accept icmp redirects) on the routers?